# how to get the body of a database function through jdbc?

Tags: postgresql, function, jdbc

Is there a way i can get the body of a function from a postgres database through a jdbc connection? For example I have a function definition in the database like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.body,'')), 'D');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and in my Java application i would like to get that content as a String. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance,

Corneliu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get it by executing this sql:

`SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'my_function';`